# Select fictitious column headers without records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I can't believe I can't figure this out or find anything related to this.  I'm trying to generate a set of column headers dynamically but with no data (as if it was an empty table).

```
SELECT Null AS [CODE], Null AS [DESC];
```

will return

```
CODE        DESC
----------- -----------
NULL        NULL
```

which is close, but I need it to have no records:

```
CODE        DESC
----------- -----------
```

As best I can replicate the exact requirement:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    [CODE] bit NULL,
    [DESC] bit NULL
);

SELECT [CODE], [DESC]
FROM @Table;
```

Which is what I'll go with if I can't find anything similar but this just feels soooo verbose for something that feels trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `false` condition in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT Null AS [CODE], Null AS [DESC]
WHERE 1=0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2cd56170e3c6b591d6e813ed3e5809dd).
This way you can pass **any** value to the 2 columns, not just `null`.

Comment: Love it, thanks!  I feel more than just a little foolish right now :P

Answer (score 1):

Try to use CTE

```
WITH CTE AS(

 SELECT Null AS [CODE], Null AS [DESC]
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE [CODE] IS NOT NULL AND [DESC] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Wow, if you told me that a CTE would be faster than a table variable I'd never have believed it!!  Definitely the one to beat then, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT null as [Code], null as [DESC]
  WHERE 1=2
```

Comment: Thanks for this, going with @forpas as he got it in just seconds before yours :)